# Android: menu's separators is disappeared

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I'm a begginer in android development and I have a problem. My first menu has no separator lines in portreit and landscape modes. Also I've no separator in action bar in portreit mode while I have it in landscape one. Separator for action bar is a pic 1x32 placed at ./drawable.    At the same time under AVDs and Android-x86 (VirtualBox) is fine. Please, see the fig1: [image: Fig1].

Thanks in advance!

**Update 1:**

Create and show menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.main_menu_sync:
            Toast("Refresh menu");
                return true;
            case R.id.main_menu_more:
                Toast("More menu");
                return true;

                 // ...

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Menu layout (./res/menu/main_menu.xml):

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_undo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_undo"
    android:title="Undo"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_multiselect"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_multiselect"
    android:title="Multiselect"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_sync"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:title="Sync"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_more"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_more"
    android:title="More">
   <menu>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_preferences"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
            android:title="Preferences"/>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_tab_order"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_tab_order"
            android:title="Tab order"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you post your code on how you're creating your menu?

Answer (score 1):

If your device is QVGA and you set the `anyDensity` attribute to false, some separators on the UI will be missing.

See more details at
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your screen is supporting the view that you are using. You should add the support screen tag to your manifest.xml file. It works for me. Or may be you can check the following link to get some more info.